# How can I convert frame rates without changing speed?

Tags: framerate

I have a video with 60fps and I know that if I keep all the frames and play it at 24fps, then I get a slow motion effect. I want to know how to make it play at 24fps while still showing things in real time.

Would it be better if I record that video again in 24 fps?

Answer (score 4):

In order to convert frame rates without impacting the speed of playback, you have to remove frames to decrease the frame rate or create new frames to speed it up.  If the frame rate is an even multiple, then this process can be done losslessly for reduction in frame rate since you simply drop every unneeded frame.

If they are not multiples or you are increasing the frame rate, then it is necessary to interpolate new frames.  Interpolation is a process by which the computer looks at the next and previous frames and invents one that looks like it would fit between them.

If you shoot at 60fps and drop it to 24fps, it is not an even multiple and frames have to be interpolated or taken at the wrong time in order to make up for the difference.  This results in a lower quality of video than shooting in 24fps to start.

Comment: How do you do this (remove frames / create new frames) natively in Premiere Pro  or After Effects (CC2104) ?

Comment: @Oliver it does this automatically. By "you" I only mean that the application must invent frames.

Comment: I really meant you, within the application, as the application do not know what you want to do when giving him a video to eat.

Comment: Yes it does, that's what interpolation is. You tell it you want a given frame rate and it invents frames as needed.  There may be settings to adjust the pull down as well, though it has been a while since I did frame rate conversion.

Answer (score 0):

If you can easily record the video again natively in 24fps, that would be your best solution. However, you may also want to investigate a tool like Twixtor, which is built to interpolate frames for jobs exactly like this one.